# Merging subsets of columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

If I have a matrix `A` in this form:

```
4  7  10 5
5  8  1  6
6  9  2  9
6  10 6  11
```

Is there a more concise and efficient way to combine subsets of columns into singular columns i.e. take A(:,1:2) and combine it into a single column and likewise for A(:,3:4) other than doing it step by step? i.e.:

```
B = A(:,1:2);
B = B(:);
C = A(:,3:4);
C = C(:);
out = horzcat(B,C);
```

Comment: Is merging the first two columns and the last two columns the only thing you want done, or is there a more general case?

Comment: More general case, with the ability to alter the number of columns being merged.

Comment: So, let's say we had a 12 column matrix... would you want something where given a list of indices... like `[3 4], [2 5], [7 9]`, you would want a three column matrix that merges columns 3-4 for the first column, 2-5 for the second column and 7-9 for the third column?  If you can, please provide more explicit directions on what it is you want.

Comment: I do not want to specify non-continuous indices - simply take (n) number of columns, merge them, then take the next (n) columns and so forth.

Comment: OK that wasn't clear in your post.  In that case, the answer below is more than adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reshape](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html). Taking your example:

```
out2 = reshape(A, size(A,1)*2, [])
```